# Huge SDL_Textures - Out of Memory

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Im programming a Prototyp of an Tilebased Game to learn SDL.My map is just a 257x257 array of Tiles, each Tile is 1x1 to 60x60 pixels (different zoomings).The SDL Window has a resolution of 1024x768. So i can display 18x13 to 1024*768 Tiles.

Till now i tried 2 approches.

**1st: Render from Tiles**

```
//for (at worst) 1024*768 Tiles
SDL_Rect Tile;
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, /*some color*/ , 255);
Tile = { Tile_size * x, Tile_size * y, Tile_size, Tile_size };
SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &(Tile));
```

con: it is way to time consuming and the game starts lagging if i try to move the map.

---

**2nd create an texture before the Game starts**

with: `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`, `SDL_FillRect`, `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`

con: the Texture would be (257x257)(Tiles)x(60x60)(pixel/Tile)x(32)(bit/pixel) ~ 951 MB. and with multiple Textures for different Zoom steps its way to huge to handle.

I'd appreciate any tips to improve the performance.

Comment: Start using SDL2 man. It's the future.

Comment: @Ludwik SDL2 is already past, not the future.

Comment: That's true too, @user1095108, but let's compromise on "present". It's not the future until SDL3 is released :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example just draws a single filled rectangle... That can't be slow, I'd have to see more to give a better answer.

In general you'll want to render **only the tiles which are visible** on the screen not the tiles on the map itself. With 60x60 tiles you can get away with just using SDL 2d drawing functions then. When you add different zoom levels I'm afraid you won't be able to just use 1x1 pixel tiles and use the same approach - you would try to call every pixel via a function call!

So once you add different zoom levels you'll have to figure out how to get that on screen - and what that's supposed to mean to the player anyway :)

Comment: thanks :) I found my Error now.
I tried Rendering the whole map every Frame and not just the visible Tiles. 
that wasn't my smartest Move.